# Footer blocking button

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a footer that's fixed to the bottom of the page but when I get to the bottom it blocks a button. How do I go about fixing this issue?

Footer.jsx

```
import "./Footer.css";

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer>
      <p>Copyright © 2022</p>{" "}
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Footer.css

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It would be easy if you can create a reproducible sample and add link, you can use codesandbox / stackblitz ... add code, save and share the link :)

Comment: Add padding to the bottom of the body equal to the height of the footer component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
footer {
  position: static;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Analysis**

You made `position: fixed` for the footer, so anything which goes behind that will gets hidden. Instead, for the footer, we can use `position: static` so that the footer will position itself with the flow.

For more info - [position at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)